# Run process, capture output and give as argument to other process, but only if inner process is successful

Tags: bash

I want to do something like:

`./process --input $(./other_process)`

But I want it to only run if `other_process` does not fail (e.g., exit code 0). Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to first capture the output of `other_process`, then check if it completed successfully, and only then run `process`.

Something like this:

```bash
input_value="$(./other_process)" && ./process --input "$input_value"
```